# How to hide constructor on a Java record that offers a public static factory method?

Tags: java, constructor, factory, java-record, static-factory

I have this simple [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) in Java:

```
public record DatePair( LocalDate start , LocalDate end , long days ) {}
```

I want all three properties (`start`, `end`, & `days`) to be available publicly for reading, but I want the third property (`days`) to be automatically calculated rather than passed-in during instantiation.

So I add a static factory method:

```java
public record DatePair( LocalDate start , LocalDate end , long days )
{
    public static DatePair of ( LocalDate start , LocalDate end )
    {
        return new DatePair ( start , end , ChronoUnit.DAYS.between ( start , end ) ) ;
    }
}
```

I want *only* this static factory method to be used for instantiation. I want to hide the constructor. Therefore, I explicitly write the implicit constructor, and mark it `private`.

```java
public record DatePair( LocalDate start , LocalDate end , long days )
{
    private DatePair ( LocalDate start , LocalDate end , long days )  // <---- ERROR: Canonical constructor access level cannot be more restrictive than the record access level ('public')
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.days = days;
    }

    public static DatePair of ( LocalDate start , LocalDate end )
    {
        return new DatePair ( start , end , ChronoUnit.DAYS.between ( start , end ) ) ;
    }
}
```

But marking that contractor as `private` causes a compiler error:

> java: invalid canonical constructor in record DatePair (attempting to assign stronger access privileges; was public)

How to hide the implicit constructor of a record if the compiler forbids marking it as `private`?

Comment: The constructor is part of the interface of an record. Removing it would break all kinds of deserialization frameworks that expect a public canonical constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is essentially impossible, in the sense that this just isn't how records work. You *may* be able to hack it together but that is very much not what records were meant to do, and as a consequence, if you do, the code will be confusing, the API will need considerable extra documentation to explain it doesn't work the way you think it does, and future lang features will probably make your API instantly obsoleted (it feels out of date and works even more weirdly now).

### The essential nature of records

Records are designed to be deconstructable and reconstructable, and to support these features intrinsically, as in, without the need to write any code to enable any of this. Records just 'get all that stuff', for free, but at a cost: They are inherently defined by their 'parts'. This has all sorts of effects - they cannot extend anything (Because that would mean they are defined by a combination of their parts and the parts their supertype declares, that's more complex than is intended), and the parts are treated as final, and you can't make it act like somehow it isn't actually just a thing that groups together its parts, which is the problem with your code.

Let's make that 'if you try to do it, future language features will ruin your day' aspect of it and focus on deconstruction and the `with` concept.

Yes, this mostly isn't part of java **yet**, but the record feature is specifically designed to be expanded to encompass deconstruction and all the features that it brings, and work is far along. Specifically, Brian Goetz, who is in charge of this feature and various features that expand on a more holistic idea (records is merely a small part of that idea), really loves this stuff and has repeatedly written about it. Including quite complete feature proposals.

Specifically, for records, you are soon going to be able to write this (note, as is usual with OpenJDK feature proposals, don't focus on the syntax or about concerns such as '.. but, does that mean 'with' is now a keyword?' - actual syntax is the very last thing that is fleshed out.

```
DatePair dp = ....;

DatePair newDp = dp with {
  days = 20;
}
```

The concept of a 'deconstruction' is the same as a constructor, but in reverse: Take an object and break it apart into its constituent parts. For records, this is obvious, and in fact (and this is the key, why you can't do what you want in this way), **baked in** - records deconstruct by way of the elements you listed for the record (so, here, `start`, `end`, and `days`) and you probably won't be able to change this.

The `obj with {block;}` operation is syntax sugar for:

- Deconstruct `obj`.
- For each item that the deconstruction has produced, declare a local variable.
- Run `block`. The local vars are available, and aren't final - change whatever you want.
- Construct a new object of the same type as `obj`, using those local vars to pass to its constructor.

Your idea can only work if the deconstructor deconstructs solely into `LocalDate start` and `LocalDate end`, leaving `long days` out of it entirely. It would require records to be able to state: Actually, *this* is my constructor, with different arguments from the record's component list, and once you open the door to writing your own constructor, you therefore then also **have to** write your own deconstructor.

The thing is, there is no syntax for deconstructors right now. Thus, if records did allow you to write your own constructor (with a different list of params than the record components), that means that if in the future a language feature is released such as `with`, that requires a deconstructor, that some records can't support it. That's annoying to the java lang team: They'd love to say: "We introduced `with`, which works with all records already! In the future once we release the deconstructor feature it should also be usable for classes that have a deconstructor".

That is to say, while I can't say I 100% know exactly what Brian and the OpenJDK team is thinking, I'd be *incredibly* surprised if they aren't thinking like the above.

The point of the above dive into OpenJDK's plans for near-future java is to explain that [A] why you can't make your own constructor in records, and [B] why there won't be a language feature coming along that will, unless it is part of a set of very significant updates (including deconstructor syntax, and that won't happen unless there are features that use it).

### Good news!

Fortunately, there are very simple alternate strategies you can use here.

This seems to be the best fit for your needs, usable in today's java:

```
public record DatePair(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
  public long days() {
    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
  }
}
```

This removes `days` from being treated as a component part of DatePair, but then, *that is the point* - components in records fundamentally can be changed independently of the other parts of it (possibly you can add code that then says the new state is invalid, but now you force folks to set `start` and `days` both simultaneously, you can't 'calculate it out', which seems like API so bad you wouldn't want such a thing).

It also suffers from the notion that days is now calculated every time instead of being 'cached'. You can solve that by writing your own cache e.g. with guava cachebuilder but that's quite a big bazooka to kill a mosquito. If this truly is the calculation you need, it's relatively cheap, I'd just write it like this and not worry about performance unless you are holding a profiler report that says this days calculation is the key culprit.

If this still isn't acceptable, then the thing you want just isn't what `record` represents. You might as well ask how you represent arbitrary strings with an `enum`. You just cannot do that - that is not what enums are about. Hence, you end up at:

```
import lombok.*;

@Value
@lombok.experimental.Accessors(fluent = true)
public class DatePair {
  @With private final LocalDate start, end;
  @With private final long days;

  public DatePair(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
  }
}
```

I *strongly* recommend you don't add the accessors line (this turns `getStart()` into just `start()`. Records notwithstanding, `get` is just better (it plays far better with auto-complete which is ubiquitous in java editor environments, and is more common. In fact, the java core libs themselves do it 'right' and use `get`, see e.g. `java.time.LocalDate`). But, if you really really want it - that's how you do it. Or add a `lombok.config` file and say there that you want fluent style accessor names.

Or let your IDE generate it all, which will be a ton of code you'll have to maintain. I understand the 'draw' of using records here, but records can't do lots of things. They can't extend anything either. They can't memoize calculated stuff by way of a field either.

Comment: Alternatively, create a `public sealed interface` declaring the `static` factory method and the accessor methods and a non-public `record` type as the only implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The JLS specifies in [8.10.4. Record Constructor Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10.4) that the canonical constructor must have at least the visibility as the record itself:

> Either way, an explicitly declared canonical constructor must provide at least as much access as the record class, as follows:
>
> - If the record class is public, then the canonical constructor must be public; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the record class is protected, then the canonical constructor must be protected or public; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the record class has package access, then the canonical constructor must not be private; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the record class is private, then the canonical constructor may be declared with any accessibility.

Otherwise you cannot deserialize the record, as indicated in [8.10. Record Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10):

> The serialization mechanism treats instances of a record class differently than ordinary serializable or externalizable objects. In particular, a record object is deserialized using the canonical constructor (§8.10.4).

Would be difficult for the serialization mechanism to deserialize such a (visible) class, if it can't call the canonical constructor to initialize the fields. However, you can set the "correct" `days` field in the canonical constructor, ignoring the `days` parameter coming into the constructor:

```
public record DatePair( LocalDate start , LocalDate end , long days )
{
    public DatePair ( LocalDate start , LocalDate end , long days )
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between ( start , end );
    }

    public static DatePair of ( LocalDate start , LocalDate end )
    {
        return new DatePair ( start , end , ChronoUnit.DAYS.between ( start , end ) ) ;
    }
}
```

See example on https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/KEU. You can keep the static `DatePair.of()` method for convenience.

Comment: See my answer - "if you `with` a DatePair instance and change its `days` value, absolutely nothing happens whatsoever" is _exactly_ the kind of "do not do this - your API will be bizarre and feels obsolete and you needs loads of docs to explain why all sorts of stuff that records just get / gain over time doesn't work" situation I describe.

Answer (score -1):

> How to hide the *implicit* constructor of a record if the compiler
> forbids marking it as private?

I would argue that the canonical constructor of a record is very *explicit* (but that may be semantics). The record specification makes it clear that the canonical constructor is public. Changing that would go against the record's reason to exist.

You can achieve what you want with a regular class.

Comment: ”implicit” is used 25 times in [*JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), and “explicit” 21 times. For example, “if the canonical constructor is implicitly declared”.